# Is It Safe to Add/Remove Element To/From Map while Iterating the Map

Tags: c++, linux, dictionary, stl, iterator

While iterating a map, is it safe to add/remove elements to/from this map? Please see below pseudo code:

```
       //Pseudo Code
       //test is a global variable
       map<int, CustomClass*> test;
       test[Index1] = new CustomClass;
       test[Index2] = new CustomClass;
       test[Index3] = new CustomClass;

       ... 
       //Iterating the map
       map<int, CustomClass*>::iterator itor;
       itor = test.begin();
       while(itor != test.end())
       {
            if (itor->first == IndexToRemove)
            {
                   //below function will remove 
                   //element from the map
                   RemoveFromMap(IndexToRemove);
            } 

            if (NeedAddNewElement())
            {
                   //below function will add
                   // an element to the map
                   AddNewElement(IndexToAdd);
            }

            itor++;
       }

       //Remove a mapping from map
       void RemoveFromMap(int index)
       {
            map<int, CustomClass*>::iterator itor;
            itor = test.begin();
            while(itor != test.end())
            {
                 if (itor->first == index)
                 {
                      test.erase(itor);
                      break;
                 }

                 itor++;
             }
        }

       //add new mapping to map
       void AddNewElement(int index)
       {
            //chech if index exists
            if (test.find(index) == test.end())          
             {           
                    test[index] = new CustomClass;           
             }
       }
```

Comment: Why do you iterate? You can use Erase and Insert directly

Comment: @schoetbi just psedo code, there are bunch of code there for every mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[operator[]](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) does not invalidate iterators:

> No iterators or references are invalidated.

but [erase](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase) invalidates all iterators and references to the erased element while other iterators are not affected:

> References and iterators to the erased elements are invalidated. Other references and iterators are not affected.

*erase* in your case does return `Iterator following the last removed element.`.

Comment: what about adding new element? is it safe to do that?

Comment: @StevePeng that is covered by `operator[]` which as I mentioned in my answer does not invalidate any iterators or references

Answer (score 2):

While iterating through a container and erasing the element the iterator points to the iterator itself becomes invalid!

Hence:

```
iterator = container.erase(iterator)
```

getting the next valid iterator.